# How to request information from amazon URL

Tags: web-services, datetime, amazon-web-services

Could anyone explain me what information should I put from this URL:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
Operation=ItemSearch&
ItemId=B000Q678OO&
ResponseGroup=Images&
SearchIndex=Blended&
Version=2011-08-01
&Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
&Signature=[Request Signature]
```

AWSAccessKeyId: Access Key ID

Timestamp: UTC time display as YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ -> so how can i display like this to add to the url

Signature: is it the Secret Access Key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the signature is a string generated from the request parameters and the Secret Access Key.

The following article explains how to generate the signature:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html

Comment: What about the timestamp how can I generate it validly, coz I got the error Timestamp is invalid. Reason: Must be in ISO8601 format.

Comment: Are you URL encoding the timestamp? (see step 2) Should be something like Timestamp=2009-01-01T12%3A00%3A00Z